# Open a file from user input in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, user-input

How would I open a file by asking for user input? After     `raw_input("PROMPT")` requests `filename.txt` from the user, I get the error code:

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

which tells me I need to convert the user input to a string, or format it a different way.

What is the correct way of telling Python `selectfile` means "open this file"?

```
selectfile = file(raw_input("Enter Filename: "), 'r')
with open(selectfile, 'r') as inF:

with open('outputfile.txt', 'w') as f:

    for index, line in enumerate(inF):

        if myString in line:

                print "Search Term Found!"

                f.write("Line %d has string: %s" % (index, line))

filename = "outputfile.txt"
myfile = open(filename)
lines = len(myfile.readlines())
```

Comment: The `open` statement expect a `string` while you pass it a `file`. Don't cast it in `file` and it should work.

Comment: You are opening a file _twice_

Comment: @CoryKramer I mean he shouldn't pass a file handler as an argument of `open`

Comment: Why are you using file and open?

Comment: Your code is a little inconsistent with what you're asking. Are you trying to search for a file and a specific word within that file?

Comment: @Leb, yes. I'm trying to prompt for a filename, open that filename, prompt for a search term, search that file, then output a new file containing the lines that word appears on.

Comment: @tuananh, two different files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the lines -

```
selectfile = file(raw_input("Enter Filename: "), 'r')
with open(selectfile, 'r') as inF:
```

You need to open the filename (which is inputted from user) directly, as below -

```
with open(raw_input("Enter Filename: "),'r') as inF:
```

Also, there seems to be an indentation issue in your code, seems like you really don't want to use `with` command for openning the input file, you may want to do -

```
inF = open(raw_input("Enter Filename: "),'r')
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful, tried without `with` and was able to run the program by adding `myString = "SEARCH TERM"` to test.